# How do I query this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <div class="room" data-people="jason">
    blah blah
    </div>

$(".room with attribute "data-people=jason").hide();
```

I want to select the room where data-people = jason, and then hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <div class="room" data-people="jason">
     blah blah
   </div>
   <script>
       $(".room[data-people='jason']").hide();
   </script>
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/27b45.php)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(".room[data-people=jason]").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.room[data-people=jason]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.root[data-people="jason"]').hide()
```